# SonarQube, creating issue via rest api

Tags: sonarqube

Creating issues via the rest api in the recent versions of SonarQube is not possible anymore.

Is there anyway to create issues programmatically outside of an analysis?

The issues I was able to create via the rest service in the previous versions are not related to the source code, i'm trying to do the same with the latest release

Comment: Do you refer to the 6.x releases? Did you use an internal API, or an API market as deprecated (look at the WEB-API documentation)?

Comment: Starting release 5.6 this service is no longer available. My old plugin was built on release 5.1.x and that was not deprecated. Now, what I see as first look is to implement and MeasureComputer and then import the issues data and create them at that level if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do it via the Web API since 5.6.

SonarQube is not a manual code review tool. It analyzes automatically **source code**.
Look for more information (motivation and discussions) at:

- [a forum discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonarqube/ClzDmYPRSjk/kXwaNVtXCAAJ)
- [the removal specification](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-233)

If you want to create new rules to analyze your project, you can do so in [different languages](https://docs.sonarqube.org/x/hQBJ). In this context, you can create issues related to your analysis.

Comment: Thanks Teryk, this is the approach I ended following